# Cómo podría sumar números que guardo en un dato String

Tags: java, android

Por ejemplo: Tengo un String en donde voy guardando una sumatoria y después quiero pasar ese dato String a int para poder sacar el resultado de la suma de todos esos números que he ido guardando...

```
String cadenanumeros = "+0+4+3+4+5";

int suma = Integer.parseInt(cadenanumeros);
```

Al realizar el Integer.parseInt(cadenanumeros); me arroja el siguiente error en el Logcat:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "+0+4+3+4+5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular el resultado lo podrias hacer de esta forma

```
String numero1 = "0";
String numero2 = "1";

int suma = Integer.parseInt(numero1) + Integer.parseInt(numero2);
```

De esta forma el resultado es 2

Entonces, deberias de incluir un String por cada valor que quieres sumar.

Te tira `NumberFormatException` por que estas tratando de parsear una cadena entera de strings con caracteres que no son numeros

Una forma un poco mas linda y con mejor practica seria hacer esto

```
  String input = "43 68 9 23 318"; //Declaramos los numeros a sumar
  String numeros[] = input.split("\\s+");   // Separamos los numeros de entrada
  int sum = 0; //inicializamos el sumador en 0
  for (String numero : numeros) {  // Loopeamos por todos los numeros en el string array
    Integer n = Integer.parseInt(numero);  // parseamos cada numero
    sum += n;     // sumamos los numeros
  }
  Log.i("Resultado: ",""+sum);  // mostramos el resultado
```

Comment: Muy buena explicación amigo, muchas gracias!

Comment: Ningun problema, lo que necesites consulta

Comment: split("\\s+"); lo que va a hacer es agarrar los espacios en blanco entre medio de los numeros y por mas separados que esten siempre te va a agarrar los numeros , 43 68 9 ....

Comment: De esa forma no se puede sumar un string que contenga un signo +? Por ejemplo: int suma = integer.parseint("+1+2") + integer.parseint("0")

Comment: Otra consulta, en el segundo ejemplo que me diste, es posible contar el número de espacios que existen en toda la cadena de números?

Comment: Lo qué pasa es que con el signo + lo que buscaba hacer era poder contar el número de signos + que existían en la cadena de números y de esta manera saber cuántos números existían en la cadena, para luego poder sacar un promedio con el resultado de la suma de todos los números... No sé si se entiende jajajaja

Comment: sisi, te entiendo, te lo respondi en la otra pregunta que hiciste sobre eso :)